# Linear Transformation of Circle to Hyperbola

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, hyperbolic-geometry

Circle $x^2+y^2=1  \rightarrow x^2-y^2=1 $
Given linear transformation above, I need to find the standard matrix (2*2) of such linear transformation.
 (If there is no such transformation matrix, i need to explain why)

Comment: There are projective transformations, but not linear. The linear transformation of a circle is an ellipse, not a hyperbola.

Comment: A relevant link: http://users.math.uoc.gr/~pamfilos/eGallery/problems/HyperbolaGeneration.html.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** How do linear transformations affect area? That is, if a linear transformation, with matrix $M$, carries $A$, $B$, $C$ to $A^\prime$, $B^\prime$, $C^\prime$, then how is the area of $\triangle ABC$ related to the area of $\triangle A^\prime B^\prime C^\prime$? Then: What can you say about areas of triangles inscribed in a circle vs inscribed on a hyperbola?

Answer (score 0):

**just a hint**

A point of the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ is
$(\cos (t),\sin (t)) $.

A point of the hyerbola $x^2-y^2=1$ is
$(\cosh (t),\sinh (t)) .$

Comment: So is the transformation like... $(f(t), g(t)) \mapsto (fh(t), gh(t))$; that is, the "stick an $h$ on it" function?

Comment: @pjs36 No, it  is hyperbolic cosinus denoted $\cosh $.

Comment: can there be linear transformation if it's T: x=+-1 $\rightarrow x^2-y^2 =1$ ??